# 0 definitions of operator "*" match here for signed type (numeric_std, VHDL)

Tags: fpga, vhdl, libero

I'm writing a package to add supporting functions and types for creating an FIR filter. In the `mult` function, I'm trying to multiply two signed types, which should be supported in `IEEE.numeric_std` library. The error I'm getting (using Libero IDE) is:

```
0 definitions of operator "*" match here
```

Here's the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package fir_pkg is
    constant taps : integer := 8;
    constant bit_width : integer := 8;
    type fract is array(bit_width-1 downto 0) of std_logic;
    type fract2 is array((2*bit_width)-1 downto 0) of std_logic;
    type fract_sequence is array(taps-1 downto 0) of fract;
    type fract2_sequence is array(taps-1 downto 0) of fract2;
    function mult(a,b: fract_sequence) return fract2_sequence;
end package fir_pkg;

package body fir_pkg is

    function mult(a,b: fract_sequence) return fract2_sequence is
        variable a_s, b_s:signed(bit_width-1 downto 0);
        variable seq: fract2_sequence;
    begin
        for i in a'range loop
            a_s := signed(a(i));
            b_s := signed(b(i));
            seq(i) := a_s * b_s;
        end loop;
        return seq;
    end mult;

end fir_pkg;
```

Comment: This is complaining that there isn't a "*" operator with a signature [signed, signed return fract2]. You've defined a type but provided no overload operator "*" that supports the signature. That implies you might want to type convert something.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be exactly the problem now (I've got the product on a signed variable now and am equating `seq(i)` in the next statement. How can I create conversion operators from signed to my custom type (still based on `std_logic`)?

Comment: Update: fixed using custom defined type conversion function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show me why you can't make fract and fract2 subtypes of std_logic_vector:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package fir_pkg is
    constant taps : integer := 8;
    constant bit_width : integer := 8;

    subtype fract is std_logic_vector (bit_width-1 downto 0);
    -- type fract is array(bit_width-1 downto 0) of std_logic;
    -- type fract2 is array((2*bit_width)-1 downto 0) of std_logic;
    subtype fract2 is std_logic_vector(2*bit_width-1 downto 0);

    type fract_sequence is array(taps-1 downto 0) of fract;
    type fract2_sequence is array(taps-1 downto 0) of fract2;
    function mult(a,b: fract_sequence) return fract2_sequence;
end package fir_pkg;

package body fir_pkg is

    function mult(a,b: fract_sequence) return fract2_sequence is
        variable a_s, b_s:signed(bit_width-1 downto 0);
        variable seq: fract2_sequence;
    begin
        for i in a'range loop
            a_s := signed(a(i));
            b_s := signed(b(i));
            seq(i) := std_logic_vector(a_s * b_s);
        end loop;
        return seq;
    end mult;

end fir_pkg;
```

Comment: Fairly new to VHDL. Had never heard about `subtype`. Thanks!

Comment: A little better solution: use `signed` directly instead of `std_logic_vector`.

Comment: See, here's the problem, you're not showing how they are used. You could also simply used range constrained integers.

Comment: Does integer have support for the multiplication operator?

Answer (score 1):

`fract2` is not compatible with `signed`, and so no multiplier function can be found with the correct return type.

Change the definition of `fract` and `fract2` to this:

```
subtype fract is signed(bit_width-1 downto 0);
subtype fract2 is signed((2*bit_width)-1 downto 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the result of product was expected to be `signed` but was `fract2` (custom type defined here) instead.

So, we need to create a function to convert the type. Type conversion is explained [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/typeconv.html).

The code for the conversion function here:

```
function conv_fract2(a:signed) return fract2 is
    variable var:fract2;
begin
    assert a'length = bit_width;
    for i in a'range loop
        var(i) := a(i);
    end loop;
    return var;
end conv_fract2;
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to self-answer a question. But, you should also show where to call your new convert function. Only this makes your answer helpful for further readers.